# How to call async Task<ActionResult> from angular controller

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

This is my angular controller

```
        //Save AddNewEmployee functionality 
        EDC.SaveNewEmployee = function () {
            if (EDC.AddNewEmployeeFormValidator.validate()) {
                var UserID = '0',
                CandidateSubmit = '';
                if (EDC.isEdit) {
                    UserID = EDC.rowIdToEdit;
                }
                EmployeeDetailService.SaveNewEmployee(EDC.NewEmpAdd, UserID, CandidateSubmit).then(function (response) {
                    //Close popup window 
                    EDC.AddNewEmployeeWindow.data("kendoWindow").close();
                    //EDC.NewEmpSave = response;
                    EDC.EmployeeDetailsGrid.dataSource.read();

                });
            }
        };
```

Andthis one is my MVC Controller.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> SavePermanentEmployee(Employee model)
    {
        //Sending mail to BU
        string DisplayName = "New Employee";
        //Sending mail to Employee
        string EmpDisplayName = "Price credentials";
        BAL_Employee objBalEmp = new BAL_Employee();
        Price_PMS_DAL.Employee emp = new Price_PMS_DAL.Employee();
        emp.ID = model.ID;
        emp.EmpID = model.employeeID ?? Convert.ToString(model.employeeID).ToUpper();
        emp.ReferredBy = model.referredby;
        emp.DOJ = model.dateOfJoining;
        emp.Status = 1;
        emp.Email = model.email;
        emp.BUID = model.businessUnitID;
        emp.ShiftID = model.ShiftID;
        emp.ModifiedBy = Session["EmpID"].ToString();
        var lstNewEmployeeCreated = BAL_Employee.GetEmployees();
        var result = lstNewEmployeeCreated.Where(s => s.employeeID == emp.EmpID).FirstOrDefault();

        if (result != null)
        {
            return Json("Employee ID already exists.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {

            int empSave = objBalEmp.UpdateEmployee(emp);
            BAL_Login objBalLog = new BAL_Login();
            if (empSave == 1)
            {
                TempData["Datarefresh"] = "refresh";
                lstemp = null;
                string[] datastr = emp.Email.Split(new string[] { "@" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                int empLoginSave = objBalLog.AddUser(new Price_PMS_DAL.Login { UserName = datastr[0].Trim(), EmpID = emp.EmpID, BUID = emp.BUID, ShiftID = emp.ShiftID });
                if (empLoginSave == 1)
                {
                    var data = BAL_Employee.FilterEmployeeByParam("Select TOP 1 * FROM Employee where Status=1 order by EmpID desc");
                    Price_PMS_DAL.Emp_Leave modelBal = new Price_PMS_DAL.Emp_Leave();
                    modelBal.EmpID = emp.EmpID;
                    int empLeavebalSave = objBalEmp.CreateEmployeeLLeaveBalRec(modelBal);
                    if (empLeavebalSave == 1)
                    {
                        Price_PMS_BAL.Models.BusinessUnit.BU Bus = BAL_BU.GetSPBUs().Where(b => b.ID == model.businessUnitID).First();
                        if (Bus != null)
                        {
                            //Sending Mail to BU when new Permanent employee added into the system
                            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                            StringBuilder cc = new StringBuilder();
                            StringBuilder to = new StringBuilder();
                            to.Append(@" " + Bus.BUHeadEmailId);
                            str.Append(@"Hello,<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;New Employee named <b>" + model.name + "</b> has been added to " + Bus.BUName + " BU " + " on " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Regards,<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;PRICE");
                            bool x = await Price_PMS_BAL.Models.Email.Email.SendEmail(cc, to, "New Employee Added", str.ToString(), DisplayName);
                            //End
                        }
                        //Sending Mail to Employee when new Permanent employee added into the system
                        if (emp != null)
                        {
                            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                            StringBuilder cc = new StringBuilder();
                            StringBuilder to = new StringBuilder();
                            to.Append(@" " + emp.Email);

                            //Username with last name Split
                            String[] Emailstring = emp.Email.Split(new[] { '@' });
                            String username = Emailstring[0];                   

                            //Username split with out last name

                            String[] Uname = username.Split(new[] { '.' });
                            String Unamestr = Uname[0];
                            Unamestr = Unamestr.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + Unamestr.Substring(1);
                            var PriceURL = "https://price.dreamorbit.com/";
                            str.Append(@"Hi " + Unamestr + ",<br><br>&nbsp;Welcome to DreamOrbit. Please login to PRICE (Projects, Resource Information & Cost Estimation) to apply for your leaves and to see your ratings etc. on a regular basis with following credentials:<br><br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><u>URL</u></b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:  <a href=" + PriceURL + " target=_blank>" + PriceURL + "</a>  <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><u>Username</u></b> :  " + username + "<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><u>Password</u></b> : [Your System Password]<br><br><br>&nbsp;We wish you a long and mutually beneficial association with DreamOrbit. For any queries please reach out to Panchali (panchali.bharali@dreamorbit.com).<br><br>&nbsp;Regards,<br>&nbsp;PRICE");
                            bool x = await Price_PMS_BAL.Models.Email.Email.SendEmail(cc, to, "PRICE Credentials", str.ToString(), EmpDisplayName);
                        }
                        //End

                        return Json("Saved Successfully", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                    else { return Json("Error occurred while saving data ", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); }
                }
                else
                    return Json("Error occurred while saving data ", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
            else
            {
                return Json("Error occurred while saving data ", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually javascript code execute synchronously(default) and javascript has core promise object which is use to make function asynchronous.

Angularjs has core service $q which is use to make function asynchronous.

Angularjs simple example :

```js
angular.module("starter", [])
.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $q, $http){

    var GetData = function(){
        var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
        var defer = $q.defer();
        
        $http({
            method: "GET", 
            url: root + '/posts/1'
        }).then(function(response){
            //success call back
            defer.resolve(response);
        }, function(error){
            //error callbcall
            defer.reject();
        });
        return defer.promise;
    }; 

    $scope.AsynchCall = function(){
    GetData().then(function(response){
        //success call back        
        console.log(response);
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));  
    }, function(error){
        //error callbcall
        console.log(JSON.stringfy(error));
        alert(error);  
    });
    }; 
});
```

```html
<html>
<head> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head> 

<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
<button ng-click="AsynchCall()"> Asynch call </button> 
</body> 

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because JSON.stringify will return the return value of the toJSON function if it exists.